# Dynamic injection of directive inside another directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I'm new to AngularJS and I think I misunderstood something. Im trying to inject dynamically a directive inside another directive template.

For instance I have 2 directives "a-tag" and "b-tag" and I would like to add one of these 2 directives inside another directive "container".

I have something like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <container item="a-tag" a-color="#f00"></container>
</body>
```

I declared my "container" directive to get the item attribute (a-tag, b-tag, or any other directive) and inject it.

```
angular.module("Container", []).directive("container", function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: {
            item: "@"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var template = '<div id="container">';
            var item = '';
            if(scope.item !== undefined){
                item = '<' + scope.item;
                item += ' ></' + scope.item + '>';
            }
            template += item + '</div>';
            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

It is working but i dunt know how to broadcast to my child directive (a/b,etc.) his attributes (for instance a-color="#f00" like used in the first piece of code).

My child directives look like this:

```
angular.module("A", []).directive("aTag", function(){
   return {
       restrict: "EA",
       templateUrl: "template/a.html",
       replace: true,
       link: function(scope, element, attrs){
           element.css("color", attrs.bColor);
       }
   };
});
```

It is a simple example. Actually I designed a modal popup (my container) and I would like to use it for several things such as displaying a form, a loader (my directives a-tag, b-tag, etc).

Any idea is welcome.

Ty,

Rémi